# Can't delete my tweets!

Tags: twitter

I want to delete a few tweets in Twitter, but the problem is Twitter doesn't let me. When I click on "Delete" under my tweet, it disappears for a second and then comes back. I thought this could be a temporary problem in Twitter; I've been trying this since last night but to no avail. Am I missing something? What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug related issues should be dm (direct messaged) to [@support](http://twitter.com/support).
Or submit a twicket -> [bit.ly/twicket](http://bit.ly/twicket)